# SVN - Add Ignore Rule without overwriting exitsting rules

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're using TortoiseSVN. We've always managed the ignore property by manually adding each folder/file into the ignore list.

I've just seen that TortoiseSVN has the option to add an ignore rule recursively - but it seems to overwrite the existing ignore rules (I found this out the hard way).

Surely there is a way to get round this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's some odd behavior. You could try manually setting the ignore and global-ignores properties:

Go to TortoiseSVN -> Properties on the folder containing things you want ignored, you can set the svn:global-ignores (recursive ignores, this is what the ignore (recursive) feature sets), along with the regular svn:ignore feature to keep your currently ignored files.